# Creating API to get data from database with async await style of code

Tags: node.js, async-await

I am trying to use async-await style of code throughout my app which is simple way to do async operation without any callback methods. I was able to do this for creating a wrapper apis for some external apis using "request-promise" module. But I am not sure if there are any similar thing available for contacting to database. I am completely trying to avoid callbacks.

Please let me know if anyone can help me in this regard. Let me know if you need any more information.

Comment: which database are you using?

Comment: I am using mysql. But if there are any general solution that can be awesome

Comment: General? Async functions are promises. So that means you can ```await``` a function that returns a promise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**await** requires its passed function to return a promise.

Seems like there are 2 things you can do.

1. Make your function, the one that interacts with the db(the one that performs asynchronous task) return a new Promise and then await the promise returned.
2. Use a library that performs MYSQL operations and return a promise . ex: https://www.npmjs.com/package/promise-mysql